# Java How to Parse SOAPMessage

Tags: java, xml, parsing, soap

I am using w3schools CelciusToFahrenheit example.

```
String soapEndpointUrl = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx";
//https://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit
String soapAction = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
```

This is my SoapResponse calling method which is a valid xml.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        soapResponse.writeTo(bout);

        soapConnection.close();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String xml = bout.toString("UTF-8"); // <-- The XML SOAP response
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
        xmlDocument.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        }
```

w3schools xml response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/"><CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>212</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult></CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

İ can't just get the value because dom parser can't parse and thinks document is null.

***Long story short; How can i PARSE or GET value from SOAPesponse***?